# Variable doesn't exist outside of post function

Tags: java, android

How would i make it so that i can reference my variable `tag_found` outside of the `TrakkRestClient.post` function so i can check if both that and `user_found` are true and then run code based on that?

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RequestParams tag_params = new RequestParams("Tag_ID", tag_id.getText().toString());
            TrakkRestClient.post("check/item", tag_params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] header, JSONObject response){
                    if (response.toString().contains("No")){
                        TrakkRestClient.post("log/add/in", tag_params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler());
                        Boolean tag_found = false;
                    }else if (response.toString().contains("found")){
                        Boolean tag_found = true;

                    }else{
                        show_err_tag();
                    }
                    Log.d("log",response.toString());
                }
            });
            RequestParams user_params = new RequestParams("email", user_email.getText().toString());
            TrakkRestClient.post("check/user", user_params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] header, JSONObject response){
                    if (response.toString().contains("found")){
                        final Boolean user_found = true;
                    }
                    else{
                        show_err_user();
                    }
                    Log.d("log",response.toString());
                }
            });
            Log.d("tag",tag_found.toString());
```

Comment: Just declare the variables outside of the `onClick` method first, and then assign them inside

Answer (score 0):

Make it a global variable, it will accessible anywhere

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    Boolean tag_found = false;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        RequestParams tag_params = new RequestParams("Tag_ID", tag_id.getText().toString());
        TrakkRestClient.post("check/item", tag_params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] header, JSONObject response){
                if (response.toString().contains("No")){
                    TrakkRestClient.post("log/add/in", tag_params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler());
                   tag_found = false;
                }else if (response.toString().contains("found")){
                   tag_found = true;

                }else{
                    show_err_tag();
                }
                Log.d("log",response.toString());
            }
        });
        RequestParams user_params = new RequestParams("email", user_email.getText().toString());
        TrakkRestClient.post("check/user", user_params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] header, JSONObject response){
                if (response.toString().contains("found")){
                    final Boolean user_found = true;
                }
                else{
                    show_err_user();
                }
                Log.d("log",response.toString());
            }
        });
        Log.d("tag",tag_found.toString());
```